# Why Promise.race([Promise.resolve(1), 2]).then(console.log) returns 1 instead of 2?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

Why does this behavior happen with `Promise.race()`, that Promise.resolve(1) calculates faster rather than just 2?

```js
Promise.race([Promise.resolve(1), 2]).then(console.log)
```

Comment: Because you're racing an already-settled promise and a value, so you just get whichever's first.

Comment: @jonrsharpe eh, this is a byproduct of the spec rather than an intentional design decision. It was very close to a different design where the 2 would win the race at several points in the spec process. I do agree the current design is probably better but I also agree with OP that it's not-obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race)

> If the iterable contains one or more non-promise value and/or an already settled promise, then Promise.race will settle to the first of these values found in the array

```
const foreverPendingPromise = Promise.race([]);
const alreadyFulfilledProm = Promise.resolve(100);

const arr = [foreverPendingPromise, alreadyFulfilledProm, "non-Promise value"];
const arr2 = [foreverPendingPromise, "non-Promise value", Promise.resolve(100)];
const p = Promise.race(arr);
const p2 = Promise.race(arr2);

console.log(p);
console.log(p2);
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("the stack is now empty");
  console.log(p);
  console.log(p2);
});

// logs, in order:
// Promise { <state>: "pending" }
// Promise { <state>: "pending" }
// the stack is now empty
// Promise { <state>: "fulfilled", <value>: 100 }
// Promise { <state>: "fulfilled", <value>: "non-Promise value" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `Promise.race` and `Promise.all` implicitly call `Promise.resolve` on arguments and the 1 just comes before the 2.

This is also true for the values returned from `then` callbacks, things you `await` and several other places and the idea was to make it easier to inter-op between promise and non-promise code.